# Incorrect mapping of a texture on a rectanlge in Open GL ES

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

My rectangle's vertices are defined like this :

```
0------1
|      |
|      |
2------3
```

This rectangle is modelized with the two following triangles : 0,2,3 and 0,3,1.

This list of six vertices is then mapped to the texture coordinates like this :

```
0.0f,0.0f
0.0f,1.0f
1.0f,1.0f
0.0f,0.0f
1.0f,1.0f
1.0f,0.0f
```

But the texture is not correctly mapped...

My texture image is there :

[image]

and the result I get on the screen is :

[image]

Does anybody see where I'm messing up?

The way I transfer the texture to Open GL :

```
    pointeurSurTexture = GLES31.glGetUniformLocation(programme, "texture");
    pointeurSurCoordonnéesTexture = GLES31.glGetAttribLocation(programme, "coordonneesTexture");

    GLES31.glActiveTexture(GLES31.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES31.glBindTexture(GLES31.GL_TEXTURE_2D, pointeursSurTextures[0]);
    GLES31.glUniform1i(pointeurSurTexture, 0);
    GLES31.glVertexAttribPointer(pointeurSurCoordonnéesTexture, NB_COORDONNEES_PAR_POINT_TEXTURE2D,
            GLES31.GL_FLOAT, false,NB_COORDONNEES_PAR_POINT_TEXTURE2D*OCTETS_PAR_FLOAT,
            tableauCoordonnéesTextures);
    GLES31.glEnableVertexAttribArray(pointeurSurCoordonnéesTexture);
```

and my fragment shader :

```
        precision mediump float;
        uniform sampler2D texture;
        varying vec4 couleurSommet;
        varying vec2 coordonneeTexture;
        void main() {
            gl_FragColor = couleurSommet *  texture2D(texture,coordonneeTexture);
        };
```

And how I draw my triangles :

```
GLES31.glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, triangles.capacity(),GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, triangles);
```

The `triangles` array contains the triangle's coordinate, expressed as vertex indexes (e.g 0,2,3,0,3,1).

Comment: You should post some code to help people better understand your code however by the looks of it, there is nothing wrong with your texture, it appears to be repeating/mirrored so you would need to make the texture not repeat if you don't want that effecty

Comment: This is almost unclear. Is the list of coordinates the list of vertex coordinates or is it the list of texture coordinates? Do you have 4 vertex coordinates and 6 indices to draw the quad? If yes, then you need 4 uv coordinates, too. In the following order: 0 - `0.0f,0.0f` 1 - `0.0f,1.0f` 2 - `1.0f,0.0f` 3 - `1.0f,1.0f`. But without any code I can guess only.

Comment: The list of texture coordinates is linked to the triangles vertices : the first triangle made with vertices 0, 2 and 3 of my rectangle are supposed to be mapped to the first three texture coordinates (0,0; 0,1; 1,1) and the second one, made with vertices 0,3 and 1 to the last three texture coordinates (0,0; 1,1; 1,0).

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Do you use `glDrawElements` or `glDrawArrays`?

Comment: Added some code to help you help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `glDrawElements`, then the vertex coordinates are looked up by the indices in the array of element indices.
But all the other attributes, like the texture coordinates, are looked up, too.

You defined have 4 vertex coordinates, which form quad with a width `w` and a height `h`:

> ```
> 0------1
> |      |
> |      |
> 2------3
> ```

```
   x  y
0: 0  0
1: w  0
2: 0  h
3: w  h
```

The quad is drawn by 2 triangles

> This rectangle is modelized with the two following triangles : 0,2,3 and 0,3,1.
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> GLES31.glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, triangles.capacity(),GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, triangles);
> ```
>
> The triangles array contains the triangle's coordinate, expressed as vertex indexes (e.g 0,2,3,0,3,1).

So you have setup an array of 4 vertex coordinates and an array of 6 indices.

When you want add texture coordinates, then you have to associate each vertex coordinate to an corresponding texture coordinate, rather than each element of the index array!
The number of vertex coordinates and texture coordinates has to be equal, but not the number of texture coordinate attributes and number of elements in the array of indices.

The vertex coordinates and texture and its attributes (in this case the texture coordinates) form a set of data. You can consider the 2 dimensional vertex coordinates (x, y) and the 2 dimensional texture coordinates as a single 4 dimensional coordinate.

```
   x  y  u  v
0: 0  0  0  0
1: w  0  1  0
2: 0  h  0  1
3: w  h  1  1
```

This means that the attribute `"texture"` has to be associated to an array of 4 texture coordinates in the following order:

```
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1
```

Comment: Well thanks again Rabbid76 for this very clear and comprehensive answer. My texxture is now perfectly applied on my rectangle.